How to Maintain Serial Communication Without Needing to Replug USB Cable in Python?
I'm working on a Python application that communicates with an RFID reader via a serial connection using PySerial. The application needs to continuously read data from the RFID reader. However, I'm encountering an issue where the serial communication only resumes properly when I unplug and then replug the USB cable, especially after stopping the program with Ctrl+C or when an error occurs.
Environment:
Language: Python 3.12
Library: PySerial
Operating System: macOS
RFID Reader Model: [Your RFID reader model]
Connection Details: USB to serial interface

Current Behavior:
After running the program and then stopping it (either through a normal shutdown or due to an error), subsequent attempts to restart the program result in no data being read from the serial port. The only workaround that consistently works is physically unplugging the USB cable of the RFID reader and plugging it back in. The commands seem to be coming through to the UHF RFID reader, as the lights are glowing, but I'm getting nothing back.
Expected Behavior:
The serial connection should automatically recover and continue reading data without the need for physically replugging the device.
Question:
What could be causing this behavior, and how can I modify my application to ensure the serial connection can be re-established without needing to physically interact with the hardware? Are there any specific settings or methods in PySerial or related to USB-serial connections on macOS that could help solve this issue?
What I have tried so far:

Using ser.reset_input_buffer() and ser.reset_output_buffer() to clear buffers.
Implementing a reconnection strategy in the exception handling block where I close the serial port and attempt to reopen it.
Adding detailed logging to check the state of the connection, which shows no data is read after a restart unless the cable is unplugged and replugged.

import serial
import threading
import time
import json
from datetime import datetime
from flask_cors import CORS
from queue import Queue
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "http://localhost:5000"}})
assigned_numbers_queue = Queue(maxsize=4)

SERIAL_PORT = '/dev/tty.usbmodem3417240901531'
BAUD_RATE = 921600
RESET_COMMAND = '$ba-bnx0-re\n'
INVENTORY_COMMAND = '$ir-bnx0-sex0-tax0-slx0-dtx1-mcx2-iqx4-fqx0-hqxF-lqx0-svx0-rfxF1-stx0-srx0-sdx1388-trx3001\n'
GO_COMMAND = '$ba-bnx0-go\n'

try:
    with open('epc_mappings.json') as f:
        epc_to_number = json.load(f)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("EPC mappings file not found.")

def process_tag(raw_epc):
    prefix_to_remove = "TR: | EP: "
    epc = raw_epc[len(prefix_to_remove):].strip().upper()
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    print(f"Detected Tag ID: {epc} - Timestamp: {timestamp}")

def read_from_serial(ser):
    while True:
        line = ser.readline().decode().strip()
        if line:
            print(f"Received: {line}")
            process_tag(line)

def send_go_command(ser):
    while True:
        ser.write(GO_COMMAND.encode())
        time.sleep(7)

def read_from_rfid():
    with serial.Serial(SERIAL_PORT, BAUD RATE, timeout=1) as ser:
        ser.write(RESET_COMMAND.encode())
        ser.write(INVENTORY_COMMAND.encode())
        threading.Thread(target=send_go_command, args=(ser,), daemon=True).start()
        while True:
            line = ser.readline().decode().strip()
            if line:
                print(f"Received: {line}")
                process_tag(line)

threading.Thread(target=read_from_rfid, daemon=True).start()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', assigned_numbers=list(assigned_numbers_queue.queue))

@app.route('/tags')
def get_tags():
    return jsonify({'assigned_numbers': list(assigned_numbers_queue.queue)})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

